# create function to accept integer value and function will return id input value is 1 then print 1 else 2 print 1,3 else 3 print 1,3,5 in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function that will print

```
function show($num){
$arr = array(1); $num1  = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=count($num);$i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        $num1 = $i++;
    }
    $i--;
    array_push($arr, $num1);
}

return (implode(',',$arr));
}
```

it shows error
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 100663304 bytes)

Comment: So what exacly is the problem?

Comment: may be i am did wrong code so can you please help out to creating function which gives me output what i explain in question.

Comment: You're incrementing `$i` as part of the `for` loop; but decrementing it again inside the loop, so the loop will never actually terminate; hence the out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function show($num){
    $i = 1;
    $count = 0;
    $numbers = array();
    while($i > 0) {
       if ($count == $num) {
          break;
        }
        $numbers[] = $i;
        $i += 2;
        $count++;
    }
    return implode(",", $numbers);
}
```

echo show(3); // Prints 1,3,5

echo show(7); //Prints 1,3,5,7,9,11,13

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it is what i exactly wanted. thanks so much for cooperation.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator, `$numbers` is undefined ?

Comment: It's not supposed to give that message unless you have specified echo show(0); In that case, declaring $numbers = array(); before the loop will do!

Comment: @omkarkshirsagar noted

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!